# PK_CMS_PAGE error when trying to create new category

Tags: magento2

I need help please. I got this error when trying to create new category.

> PK_CMS_PAGE in
>   /var/www/html/PJ/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityMetadata.php

it was working fine on the other machine .

Comment: check PHP version

Comment: Try  by clearing generated/code and generated/metadata files, not sure but it might help. Also check if primary_key is set to cms_page table in configured database at new setup.